# How to abort an interactive rebase if --abort doesn't work?

Tags: git, exit, rebase, abort, quit

I've got myself into a muddle via an interactive rebase, and I now wish to abort it.  (i.e. go back to the point before I was dropped into interactive rebase mode, in my case via `git pull --rebase`.)  The way to do this seems to be via `git rebase --abort`, but this doesn't work:

```
$ git rebase --abort
error: Ref refs/heads/master is at 55b388c141b1485b1acd9e050dbeb0eb90ef2ee7 but
expected b918ac16a33881ce00799bea63d9c23bf7022d67
fatal: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/heads/master'.
Could not move back to refs/heads/master
```

How can I get out of interactive rebase mode, and clean up all references to it?  (`git reset --hard` succeeds, but doesn't drop me out of rebase mode.)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try to follow the advice you see on the screen, and first reset your master's HEAD to the commit it expects.

```
git update-ref refs/heads/master b918ac16a33881ce00799bea63d9c23bf7022d67
```

Then, abort the rebase again.

Comment: Calling that an "advice" is the most undeserved compliment I can think of for whoever is in charge of the horrible Git UX

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), a `git rebase --abort` should be more reliable:

"[`git rebase <upstream> <tag>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7cebe73dbd34f68b4c97b43f3d338031fd5e3831/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> failed when aborted in the middle, as it mistakenly tried to write the tag object instead of peeling it to HEAD.

See [commit 7740ac6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7740ac691d8e7f1bed67bcbdb1ee5c5c618f7373), [commit 1d18826](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d188263e0847fd356d7ff245c32e8ebb29115b3), [commit 35f070b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35f070b4de8fa01c11d9478297ea074d633bd7d5) (21 Sep 2021), and [commit d045719](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d045719ac8ab2b2c6f4d7ce61ad3d35843556bbf), [commit 1e14bc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e14bc11ed01e876809e62d2b13db71d6c0d265c), [commit 0b7ae73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b7ae738a6a166d3b60af68c9b0984971baa7718), [commit 54627db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54627db03a60baec8fee7390b25b6ac806a9ecff), [commit 7390c65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7390c65df4fa997563ee2d1f61acd6ebb9697eac), [commit e505f45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e505f452d4e7d0d4b603b1332ad742e74a5d5374), [commit f20c1fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f20c1fb296be2a18426541573146159fdbcc668c) (13 Sep 2021) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7cebe73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cebe73dbd34f68b4c97b43f3d338031fd5e3831), 06 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7740ac691d8e7f1bed67bcbdb1ee5c5c618f7373): dereference tags
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> A rebase started with '[`git rebase <A> <B>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7740ac691d8e7f1bed67bcbdb1ee5c5c618f7373/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> is conceptually to first `checkout <B>` and run `git rebase <A>` starting from that state.
> '[`git rebase --abort`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7740ac691d8e7f1bed67bcbdb1ee5c5c618f7373/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L245)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---abort))</sup> in the middle of such a rebase should take us back to the state we checked out `<B>`.
>
> This used to work, even when `<B>` is a tag that points at a commit, until Git 2.20.0 when the command was reimplemented in `C`.
> The command now complains that the tag object itself cannot be checked out, which may be technically correct but is not what the user asked to do.
>
> Fix this old regression by using `lookup_commit_reference_by_name()` when parsing `<B>`.
> The scripted version did not need to peel the tag because the commands it passed the tag to (e.g '[`git reset`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7740ac691d8e7f1bed67bcbdb1ee5c5c618f7373/Documentation/git-reset.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))</sup>) peeled the tag themselves.